# PHP Form not executing

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and having trouble with a user form. The code executes and produces a page with a selection box and a submit button. The submit button should prompt a new php file. However, the code in the new PHP file is not being executed. I'm just getting a blank webpage.

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';
echo "<form action=\"accountStatusChange.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<select name=\"accountStatus\">";
echo "<option value=\"Active\">Active</option>";
echo "<option value=\"Inactive\">Inactive</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"loadAccountStatus\" value=\"Go\"/>";
echo "</form>"; 
?>
```

this is file accountStatusChange.php:

```
<html><body>
<?php
$status = $_POST['accountStatus']; 
echo $status;
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: add `print_r($_POST);` to the top of  accountStatusChange.php

Comment: can you send us the rendered html (view source). what happens if you put die('here'); at the top of accountStatusChange.php

Comment: @Steve in general, you can use the apache log to debug PHP errors. it should tell you the filename and line number of your error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make your life easier, try to change your code to:

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';
echo '
<form action="accountStatusChange.php" method="post">
<br/>
<select name="accountStatus">
<option value="Active">Active</option>
<option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="loadAccountStatus" value="Go"/>
</form>
';

?>
```

Then in second file:

```
<html><body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['accountStatus'])){
$status = $_POST['accountStatus']; 
echo $status;
}else{
 echo 'form not submitted';
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you uploaded both files to server?
2. Are both the files in the same directory?
3. You don't need to use so many echo statements; though there is no problem with your code.
4. Try with using `$_REQUEST`; like this:

   ```
   $status = $_REQUEST['accountStatus'];
   ```

---

```
<?php
    include 'Connection.php';
?>
<form action="accountStatusChange.php" method="post">
    <br/>
    <select name="accountStatus">
        <option value="Active">Active</option>
        <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="loadAccountStatus" value="Go"/>
</form>
```